# Jquery datetime picker fixed position relative to input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have datetimepicker on input field. When i scroll the page calendar is moving with scrolling. i want to fixed the calendar position to respective input field.
Please help...

Comment: Are you sure you have set it up correctly - jquery datepicker is usually offset to the input (no matter where you scroll): https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/.  Please can you create an [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, obj) {
        $(input).after($(input).datepicker('widget'));
    }
});
```